# bat-файл с последовательным выполнением команд в консоле

Tags: cmd, windows-10, bat

Помогите пожалуйста правильно написать батник. Нужно открыть консоль (cmd), выполнить в ней последовательно несколько команд:

```
..\venv\Scripts\activate.bat; --активация виртуального окружения python
cd ..\..;
cd proj\app -- переход в директорию проекта;
atom .
```

После чего консоль оставить открытой.

Answer (score 1):

Необходимая команда будет не в написанном батнике, а ключем при его запуске.

Чтобы консоль не закрылась выполните следующее

```
cmd /k your.bat
```

При вызове `bat` из `bat`, чтобы выполнялись следующие команды я использую `call`. Ваш скрипт `your.bat` примерно будет таким:

```
call myrun.bat
cd anywere
```

---

Никаких точек запят в конце строк быть не должно